# nwjs Menu and MenuItem - making context sensitive

Tags: menu, contextmenu, menuitem, nwjs

I have a context menu define din my nwjs app.  It has 4 items, including Cut, Paste, Copy, and Select All.

I would like to make the menu more aware of context.  For instance, I would like to disable paste if there is nothing in the clipboard.

I am at a loss on how to tackle this.  Don't even know where to start.  Does anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this where my menu was defined

```
$(document).on("contextmenu", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var clipboard = gui.Clipboard.get();
    if (clipboard && clipboard.get('text').length > 0) {
        menu.paste.enabled = true;
    } else {
        menu.paste.enabled = false;
    }
    menu.popup(e.originalEvent.x, e.originalEvent.y);
});
```